# How to get and update a specific object inside an array with Mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I'm having real trouble with MongoDB and Mongoose queries. The thing is, I have this `Menu` schema:

```
var menuSchema = new Schema({
    userID: String,
    name: String,
    meals: [{
        day: Number,
        hour: Number,
        minute: Number,
        aliments: [{
            name: String,
            amount: Number,
        }],
    }],
});
```

So I'd like to know how to get a specific meal or aliment and how to update them throught the `_id` value, automatically generated when I add them.

Thank you so much.

David.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally could get it working for meals, but not for aliments. I'm doing this for meals:

```
Menu.update({_id: request.params.menu_id, 'meals._id': request.params.meal_id}, {'meals.$.hour': request.body.hour)}, function(error, affected, raw) {
    response.send(error);
});
```

And this for aliments:

```
Menu.update({_id: request.params.menu_id, 'meals.aliments._id': request.params.aliment_id}, {'meals.aliments.$': {name: request.body.name, amount: request.body.amount}}, function(error, affected, raw) {
    response.send(error);
});
```

**EDIT:** ok so I looked for an answer on other posts and I found out the solution.

Looks like the $ positional operator does NOT work with multi-level arrays. Actually, it works only for 1-level arrays (that's why it works for meals but it doesn't for aliments).

So I guess the solution is splitting meals or aliments in documents and reference them with a mealID or alimentID.

I hope they add multi-level positional operator soon. It would be great.